Jenkins Job Builder with Active Choice Scriptler
I'm trying to use Jenkins Job builder Active choice parameter with scriptler, however, in the JJB documentation I can only see "groovy" example and I'm wondering whether or not might be even possible?
I also tried something like:
  - active-choices:
  name: APP
  description: APP name
  script:
    groovy: !include-raw-escape: include/script.groovy
    use-groovy-sandbox: false
  choice-type: single-select
  enable-filters: false
  fallback-script:
    groovy: |-
      return ['error:selected']
  parameters:
    - name: APP
      value: "app1"

and the script.groovy:
def response = "/tools/app-version ${APP}".execute().text
for (e in response.split('\n')) {
  def vers = vers.add(e)
}

vers

but got stuck at how should a user pass the APP as variable.

For active-choice-reactive You need to add a line for reference-variables. It takes a comma separated list.
If you don't want it to change when the other variable changes, then just use regular variable references.
https://jenkins-job-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/definition.html#variable-references
